# Resize image within script

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, blogger

how do I get this script to resize the image to width 200px height 90px ???

I have tweaked the script a few times but when I can get the image to the dimensions I want the image quality is terrible.

Can anyone know where it changes to resize the image?

```
<div id="feed-list-container"></div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
var multiFeed = {
    feedsUri: [
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 1",
            url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
            tag: ""
        },
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 2",
            url: "",
            tag: ""
        },
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 1",
            url: "",
            tag: ""
        }
    ],
    numPost: 10,
    showThumbnail: true,
    showSummary: true,
    summaryLength: 80,
    titleLength: "auto",
    thumbSize: 200,
    containerId: "feed-list-container",
    readMore: {
        text: "Selengkapnya",
        endParam: "?max-results=20"
    }
};
</script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Multi Feed Loader Script by Taufik Nurrohman
// URL: http://www.dte.web.id, https://plus.google.com/108949996304093815163/about
var mf_defaults={feedsUri:[{name:"Posting JQuery",url:"http://www.dte.web.id",tag:"JQuery"},{name:"Posting CSS",url:"http://www.dte.web.id",tag:"CSS"},{name:"Widget-Widget Blogger",url:"http://www.dte.web.id",tag:"Widget"}],numPost:4,showThumbnail:true,showSummary:true,summaryLength:80,titleLength:"auto",thumbSize:200,newTabLink:false,containerId:"feed-list-container",listClass:"list-entries",readMore:{text:"More",endParam:"?max-results=20"},autoHeight:false,current:0,onLoadFeed:function(a){},onLoadComplete:function(){},loadFeed:function(c){var d=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],a=document.getElementById(this.containerId),b=document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.src=this.feedsUri[c].url+"/feeds/posts/summary"+(this.feedsUri[c].tag?"/-/"+this.feedsUri[c].tag:"")+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+this.numPost+"&callback=listEntries";d.appendChild(b)}};for(var i in mf_defaults){mf_defaults[i]=(typeof(multiFeed[i])!==undefined&&typeof(multiFeed[i])!=="undefined")?multiFeed[i]:mf_defaults[i]}function listEntries(q){var p=q.feed.entry,c=mf_defaults,h=document.getElementById(c.containerId),a=document.createElement("div"),d="",l=c.feedsUri.length,n,k,m,g;for(var f=0;f<c.numPost;f++){if(f==p.length){break}n=(c.titleLength!=="auto")?p[f].title.$t.substring(0,c.titleLength)+(c.titleLength<p[f].title.$t.length?"&hellip;":""):p[f].title.$t;m=("summary" in p[f])?p[f].summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g," ").replace(/<.*?>/g,"").replace(/[<>]/g,""):"";m=(c.summaryLength<m.length)?m.substring(0,c.summaryLength)+"&hellip;":m;g=("media$thumbnail" in p[f])?'<img src="'+p[f].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72(\-c)?\//,"/s"+c.thumbSize+"-c/")+'" style="width:'+c.thumbSize+"px;height:"+c.thumbSize+'px;">':'';for(var e=0,b=p[f].link.length;e<b;e++){k=(p[f].link[e].rel=="alternate")?p[f].link[e].href:"#"}d+='<div class="post hentry"'+(!c.autoHeight?' style="height'+c.thumbSize+'px;overflow:hidden;"':"")+">";d+=(c.showThumbnail)?g:"";d+='<div class="post-title entry-title"><a href="'+k+'"'+(c.newTabLink?' target="_blank"':"")+">"+n+"</a></div>";d+='<div class="summary">';d+="<span"+(!c.showSummary?' style="display:none;"':"")+">";d+=(c.showSummary)?m:"";d+="</span></div>";d+='<span style="display:block;clear:both;"></span></div>'}d+="";d+='<div class="more-link"><a href="'+c.feedsUri[c.current].url.replace(/\/$/,"")+"/search/label/"+c.feedsUri[c.current].tag+c.readMore.endParam+'"'+(c.newTabLink?' target="_blank"':"")+">"+c.readMore.text+"</a></div>";a.className=c.listClass;a.innerHTML='<div class="main-title"><h4>'+c.feedsUri[c.current].name+"</h4></div>"+d;h.appendChild(a);c.onLoadFeed(c.current);if((c.current+1)<l){c.loadFeed(c.current+1)}if((c.current+1)==l){c.onLoadComplete()}c.current++}mf_defaults.loadFeed(0);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```xml
<div id="feed-list-container"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var multiFeed = {
    feedsUri: [
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 1",
            url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
            tag: ""
        },
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 2",
            url: "",
            tag: ""
        },
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 1",
            url: "",
            tag: ""
        }
    ],
    numPost: 10,
    showThumbnail: true,
    showSummary: true,
    summaryLength: 80,
    titleLength: "auto",
    thumbSize: 200,
    containerId: "feed-list-container",
    readMore: {
        text: "Selengkapnya",
        endParam: "?max-results=20"
    }
};
</script>

<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
var mf_defaults = {
  feedsUri: [{
    name: "Posting JQuery",
    url: "http://www.dte.web.id",
    tag: "JQuery"
  }, {
    name: "Posting CSS",
    url: "http://www.dte.web.id",
    tag: "CSS"
  }, {
    name: "Widget-Widget Blogger",
    url: "http://www.dte.web.id",
    tag: "Widget"
  }],
  numPost: 4,
  showThumbnail: true,
  showSummary: true,
  summaryLength: 80,
  titleLength: "auto",
  thumbSize: 200,
  thumbWidth: 200, // new setting
  thumbHeight: 90, // new setting
  newTabLink: false,
  containerId: "feed-list-container",
  listClass: "list-entries",
  readMore: {
    text: "More",
    endParam: "?max-results=20"
  },
  autoHeight: false,
  current: 0,
  onLoadFeed: function(a) {},
  onLoadComplete: function() {},
  loadFeed: function(c) {
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
      a = document.getElementById(this.containerId),
      b = document.createElement("script");
    b.type = "text/javascript";
    b.src = this.feedsUri[c].url + "/feeds/posts/summary" + (this.feedsUri[c].tag ? "/-/" + this.feedsUri[c].tag : "") + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + this.numPost + "&callback=listEntries";
    d.appendChild(b)
  }
};
for(var i in mf_defaults) {
  mf_defaults[i] = (typeof(multiFeed[i]) !== undefined && typeof(multiFeed[i]) !== "undefined") ? multiFeed[i] : mf_defaults[i]
}

function listEntries(q) {
  var p = q.feed.entry,
    c = mf_defaults,
    h = document.getElementById(c.containerId),
    a = document.createElement("div"),
    d = "",
    l = c.feedsUri.length,
    n, k, m, g;
  for(var f = 0; f < c.numPost; f++) {
    if(f == p.length) {
      break
    }
    n = (c.titleLength !== "auto") ? p[f].title.$t.substring(0, c.titleLength) + (c.titleLength < p[f].title.$t.length ? "&hellip;" : "") : p[f].title.$t;
    m = ("summary" in p[f]) ? p[f].summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "").replace(/[<>]/g, "") : "";
    m = (c.summaryLength < m.length) ? m.substring(0, c.summaryLength) + "&hellip;" : m;
    g = ("media$thumbnail" in p[f]) ? '<img src="' + p[f].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72(\-c)?\//, "/w" + c.thumbWidth + "-h" + c.thumbHeight + "-c/") + '" style="width:' + c.thumbWidth + "px;height:" + c.thumbHeight + 'px;">' : '';
    for(var e = 0, b = p[f].link.length; e < b; e++) {
      k = (p[f].link[e].rel == "alternate") ? p[f].link[e].href : "#"
    }
    d += '<div class="post hentry"' + (!c.autoHeight ? ' style="height' + c.thumbHeight + 'px;overflow:hidden;"' : "") + ">";
    d += (c.showThumbnail) ? g : "";
    d += '<div class="post-title entry-title"><a href="' + k + '"' + (c.newTabLink ? ' target="_blank"' : "") + ">" + n + "</a></div>";
    d += '<div class="summary">';
    d += "<span" + (!c.showSummary ? ' style="display:none;"' : "") + ">";
    d += (c.showSummary) ? m : "";
    d += "</span></div>";
    d += '<span style="display:block;clear:both;"></span></div>'
  }
  d += "";
  d += '<div class="more-link"><a href="' + c.feedsUri[c.current].url.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/search/label/" + c.feedsUri[c.current].tag + c.readMore.endParam + '"' + (c.newTabLink ? ' target="_blank"' : "") + ">" + c.readMore.text + "</a></div>";
  a.className = c.listClass;
  a.innerHTML = '<div class="main-title"><h4>' + c.feedsUri[c.current].name + "</h4></div>" + d;
  h.appendChild(a);
  c.onLoadFeed(c.current);
  if((c.current + 1) < l) {
    c.loadFeed(c.current + 1)
  }
  if((c.current + 1) == l) {
    c.onLoadComplete()
  }
  c.current++
}
mf_defaults.loadFeed(0);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

changed :
`/s"+c.thumbSize+"-c/` to `/w" + c.thumbWidth + "-h" + c.thumbHeight + "-c/`

and some other codes where `c.thumbSize` appears

Comment: did you test? With the changes the script stopped working.

Comment: There was a mistake in the variable `thumbHeight`, it should work now,  I dont have the full code so I can't try it,

Comment: Test the code here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default you can see the changes in real time

Comment: Test the first code I put here
  https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default code with changes doesn't work

Comment: The Code works here on this site https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default, but when testing it on the blogger I get the following error message line 514, column 140: The reference to entity "max -results "must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: sorry I managed to fix by changing the opening and closing of the script to <script type = 'text / javascript'>
// <! [CDATA [
//]]>
</script>

Comment: I added `/*<![CDATA[*/ ... /*]]>*/` to the script, you can also escape **&** `&max-results=` > `&amp;max-results=`

Comment: I would like to use columns with different colors with this script, for example: tag cars green, houses blue. for this I would need to add css in this part <div class = "post hentry" '+ (! c.autoHeight?' style = "height '+ c.thumbHeight +' px; overflow: hidden;" ': "") + " >

but for that you would need to bring it in the same position as <div id = "feed-list-container"> </div> how to do that?

Comment: Would it be possible to apply CSS to each tag?

For example in: feedsUri: [
         {
             name: "Judul Widget 1",
             url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
             tag: ""
         },
         {
             name: "Judul Widget 2",
             url: "",
             tag: ""
         },
         {
             name: "Judul Widget 1",
             url: "",
             tag: ""
         }
     ],

You could apply this css: style = "background-color: # c4dbff; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: # 000000; height: 200px"

Comment: Hmm I don't get what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I redo the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818794/add-css-in-script-is-it-possible