# add css in script, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script that a fellow here on the site helped me fix.

This is the first part of the code where you can choose and separate blog articles by tag.

Would it be possible to add CSS in this first part of the code where we have the tags Terror, Shounen, Açãoand make each tag a different color?

For example: Terror: blue - Shounen: yellow - Ação: green

[image]

This script pulls the blogger content by the tag, but all columns are the same color, I would like to add a css in each to differentiate them.

```
<div id="feed-list-container"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var multiFeed = {
    feedsUri: [
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 1",
            url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
            tag: "Terror"
        },
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 2",
            url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
            tag: "Shounen"
        },
        {
            name: "Judul Widget 1",
            url: "https://elfenliedbrazil.blogspot.com/",
            tag: "Ação"
        }
    ],
    numPost: 3,
    showThumbnail: true,
    showSummary: true,
    summaryLength: 80,
    titleLength: "auto",
    thumbSize: 200,
    containerId: "feed-list-container",
    readMore: {
        text: "Selengkapnya",
        endParam: "?max-results=20"
    }
};
</script>
```

> ```
> This is the second part of the code.
> ```

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
var mf_defaults = {
  feedsUri: [{
    name: "Posting JQuery",
    url: " ",
    tag: "JQuery"
  }, {
    name: "Posting CSS",
    url: "",
    tag: "CSS"
  }, {
    name: "Widget-Widget Blogger",
    url: " ",
    tag: "Widget"
  }],
  numPost: 4,
  showThumbnail: true,
  showSummary: true,
  summaryLength: 80,
  titleLength: "auto",
  thumbSize: 200,
  thumbWidth: 200, // new setting
  thumbHeight: 90, // new setting
  newTabLink: false,
  containerId: "feed-list-container",
  listClass: "list-entries",
  readMore: {
    text: "More",
    endParam: "?max-results=20"
  },
  autoHeight: false,
  current: 0,
  onLoadFeed: function(a) {},
  onLoadComplete: function() {},
  loadFeed: function(c) {
    var d = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
      a = document.getElementById(this.containerId),
      b = document.createElement("script");
    b.type = "text/javascript";
    b.src = this.feedsUri[c].url + "/feeds/posts/summary" + (this.feedsUri[c].tag ? "/-/" + this.feedsUri[c].tag : "") + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + this.numPost + "&callback=listEntries";
    d.appendChild(b)
  }
};
for(var i in mf_defaults) {
  mf_defaults[i] = (typeof(multiFeed[i]) !== undefined && typeof(multiFeed[i]) !== "undefined") ? multiFeed[i] : mf_defaults[i]
}

function listEntries(q) {
  var p = q.feed.entry,
    c = mf_defaults,
    h = document.getElementById(c.containerId),
    a = document.createElement("div"),
    d = "",
    l = c.feedsUri.length,
    n, k, m, g;
  for(var f = 0; f < c.numPost; f++) {
    if(f == p.length) {
      break
    }
    n = (c.titleLength !== "auto") ? p[f].title.$t.substring(0, c.titleLength) + (c.titleLength < p[f].title.$t.length ? "&hellip;" : "") : p[f].title.$t;
    m = ("summary" in p[f]) ? p[f].summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, " ").replace(/<.*?>/g, "").replace(/[<>]/g, "") : "";
    m = (c.summaryLength < m.length) ? m.substring(0, c.summaryLength) + "&hellip;" : m;
    g = ("media$thumbnail" in p[f]) ? '<img src="' + p[f].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72(\-c)?\//, "/w" + c.thumbWidth + "-h" + c.thumbHeight + "-c/") + '" style="width:' + c.thumbWidth + "px;height:" + c.thumbHeight + 'px;">' : '';
    for(var e = 0, b = p[f].link.length; e < b; e++) {
      k = (p[f].link[e].rel == "alternate") ? p[f].link[e].href : "#"
    }
    d += '<div class="post hentry"' + (!c.autoHeight ? ' style="height' + c.thumbHeight + 'px;overflow:hidden;"' : "") + ">";
    d += (c.showThumbnail) ? g : "";
    d += '<div class="post-title entry-title"><a href="' + k + '"' + (c.newTabLink ? ' target="_blank"' : "") + ">" + n + "</a></div>";
    d += '<div class="summary">';
    d += "<span" + (!c.showSummary ? ' style="display:none;"' : "") + ">";
    d += (c.showSummary) ? m : "";
    d += "</span></div>";
    d += '<span style="display:block;clear:both;"></span></div>'
  }
  d += "";
  d += '<div class="more-link"><a href="' + c.feedsUri[c.current].url.replace(/\/$/, "") + "/search/label/" + c.feedsUri[c.current].tag + c.readMore.endParam + '"' + (c.newTabLink ? ' target="_blank"' : "") + ">" + c.readMore.text + "</a></div>";
  a.className = c.listClass;
  a.innerHTML = '<div class="main-title"><h4>' + c.feedsUri[c.current].name + "</h4></div>" + d;
  h.appendChild(a);
  c.onLoadFeed(c.current);
  if((c.current + 1) < l) {
    c.loadFeed(c.current + 1)
  }
  if((c.current + 1) == l) {
    c.onLoadComplete()
  }
  c.current++
}
mf_defaults.loadFeed(0);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to explore using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Though you could also add a color code attribute to your json, and at a.innerHTML in your javascript section have it do inline css/set the `background-color` for the div.

Comment: Arthur Weborg gave an interesting answer but when testing it only the title changed color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

> Might be worthwhile to explore using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Though you could also add a color code attribute to your json, and at a.innerHTML in your javascript section have it do inline css/set the background-color for the div.

It's important to note though, there are likely many solutions to your question, this is just how I'd do it.

Your css file could look something like this:

```
div[data-tag='Terror'] {
    background-color: blue;
}
div[data-tag='Shounen'] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
div[data-tag='Ação'] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

and you'd update your javascript to include a `data-tag="'+c.feedsUri[c.current].tag+'"` on your html element of interest.

The anchor tag may not be where exactly you'd want it, but this would at least get you started in the direction I perceive you're attempting to go.

```
a.innerHTML = '<div data-tag="'+c.feedsUri[c.current].tag+'" +class="main-title"><h4>' + c.feedsUri[c.current].name + "</h4></div>" + d;
```

Comment: Hello again, I just tested the code here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default and only the widjet title changes color.

What I would like is for the background of the content to change color.

Comment: You'd likely just change where that data-tag is being added.

could be adding the data-tag snippet to this line `d += '<div class="post hentry"' + (!c.autoHeight ? ' style="height' + c.thumbHeight + 'px;overflow:hidden;"' : "") + ">";` -- don't have the time to get acquainted enough with your code to know which spot though.

Comment: Add the `data-tag="'+c.feedsUri[c.current].tag+'"` to whatever the containing div element is :)

Comment: ah actually, might be `h.dataset.tag=c.feedsUri[c.current].tag`

Comment: Now it's great thanks, just 1 more thing, would it be possible to change the number of articles in each tag?

When you change this part of the code "numPost: 4," the effect happens on all tags, would it be possible to have a quantity for each specific tag?

Comment: Cheers on the success!

Onto your follow up question, It looks like it might possible at first glance, but that'd require you to refactor your code, both the `loadfeed()` and `listEntries()` method accesses the `numPost` value. You'd need to decouple that.You'd need to at a minimum add an attribute to each object in your feedsUri instead of using the generic one from the parent object. Then you'd have to look at every reference to the `.numPost` attribute and would require making several dozen slight changes.